# folder path access is denied c# winui3

Tags: c#, windows, directory, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I’m asking the question again in more detail, today I’m creating code to move a folder to another folder, every 10-20 attempts my code works and then gives the error ex.meassage: Access to the path 'D:\BSM\BeamSkinMaster\BeamSkinMaster \bin \x86\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x86\AppX \vehicles' is denied.

[here is a folders in directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvR5T.png)

here is my code

```
namespace BeamSkinMaster.pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class PackingPage : Page
    {
        public PackingPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            MainWindow.progressBar.ShowPaused = true;
        }

        string pngpath = MainWindow.pppth + @"\" + MainWindow.endtext + "_skin_SKINNAME.png";
        string zippath = pathes.dir + @"\" + ChoosingNamePage.inttxt + ".zip";
        public static string path = pathes.dir + @"\" + MainWindow.endtext;
        string source = pathes.dir;
        string pathh = path + @"\" + "vehicles";
        

        protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            File.Delete(pngpath);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            waittext.Text = "Пакуем мод в ZIP";

            await Task.Delay(3000);
            try
            {

                // Проверяем существование исходной папки
                if (Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    // Перемещаем папку
                    string pathhh = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "vehicles");
                    string sourcee = System.IO.Path.Combine(source, "vehicles");
                    Directory.Move(sourcee, pathhh);
                    ContentDialog finish = new ContentDialog
                    {
                        Title = "Перемещение успешно",
                        Content = "Для продолжения нажимте ОК",
                        CloseButtonText = "OK",
                    };
                    finish.XamlRoot = waittext.XamlRoot;

                    ContentDialogResult result = await finish.ShowAsync();

                    finish.CloseButtonClick += (s, args) =>
                    {
                        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(uploadingUVPage), null, new SlideNavigationTransitionInfo() { Effect = SlideNavigationTransitionEffect.FromRight });
                        MainWindow.progressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;
                        MainWindow.progressBar.Value = 100;
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    ContentDialog na = new ContentDialog
                    {
                        Title = "Ошибка при перемещнии",
                        Content = "Невозможно переместить папку, так как она не существует",
                        CloseButtonText = "OK",
                    };
                    na.XamlRoot = waittext.XamlRoot;

                    ContentDialogResult result = await na.ShowAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ContentDialog error = new ContentDialog
                {
                    Title = "Ошибка при перемещнии",
                    Content = $"Невозможно переместить папку, по причине: {ex.Message}",
                    CloseButtonText = "OK",
                };
                error.XamlRoot = waittext.XamlRoot;

                ContentDialogResult result = await error.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I put my code in the "try" block, added "Path.combine" and added ContentDialog

Comment: you should properly terminate your related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77214277/how-to-move-a-directory-in-c-sharp-winui3 before posting another similar one. If you solved the other one than answer yourself with the solution for example. If it's new information, append to your other question, or delete it if it's not relevant anymore.

Comment: Is the D drive removable? Can you try if this is reproducible on the C drive?

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding no, D drive is no removable

Comment: Could you please tell us whether you could reproduce this issue on another device?

Comment: Error Message is clear... use a try catch with `catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }` this will bypass ezception if access is not granted for file/folder